# How do I handle Formik (React) onSubmit correctly for asynchronousity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

How can I prevent `onSubmit` from being triggered if the form is already submitting?
If I add something like `if (isSubmitting) return`, Formik will treat that as the `Promise` being resolved and set `isSubmitting` to `false` immediately (even if there is a previous `Promise` running).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));

const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values) => {
        console.log("submitting!!")
        await sleep(1000);
      }}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting }) => (
        <Form>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" />

          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" />

          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field name="email" placeholder="jane@acme.com" type="email" />

          <button type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could add `disabled` to `button` whenever `isSubmitting` is true. So that user cannot click if `isSubmitting` process is ongoing.

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: ""
  }}
  onSubmit={async (values) => {
    console.log("submitting!!");
    await sleep(1000);
  }}
>
  {({ isSubmitting }) => (
    <Form>
      <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
      <Field name="firstName" placeholder="Jane" />

      <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
      <Field name="lastName" placeholder="Doe" />

      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <Field name="email" placeholder="jane@acme.com" type="email" />

      <button disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </Form>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Furthermore if you want to have more control on`isSubmitting` props, you could manipulate it with `setSubmitting` in the `onSubmit` process.

```js
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: ""
  }}
  onSubmit={async (values, {setSubmitting}) => {
    setSubmitting(true) // if you want more control
    console.log("submitting!!");
    await sleep(1000);
    setSubmitting(false) // if you ant more control
  }}
>
  ...
</Formik>
```

Comment: For your latter example, won't Formik already have set it to true before invoking the callback?

Comment: @HelloWorld yes, Formik already have set it to true before invoking the callback.

Comment: so I have no idea if it is already ongoing and it doesn't give me any more control, so I have to disable the submit button, but disabling the button doesn't prevent the form from submitting if I hit enter in some browsers...

Comment: If that's the case, I think you could manipulate it with additional state to the Example component. That way you could add conditional inside the async function. I.e only execute the fetching / logic if the state is false.